# Extracting data from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to extract address from $mydata variable.

i have this code which shows me my data:

```
foreach($landerssss['domains'] as $mydata)
{
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($mydata, TRUE) . '</pre>';}
```

in the above code there is no error the lines bellow shows whats inside the $mydata variable.

This is whats inside $mydata variable:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [address] => aloran
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [address] => ozamiz
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [address] => manila
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [address] => cebu
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [address] => bacolod
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [address] => bukidnon
            [mainDomain] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [address] => davao
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [address] => boracay
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [address] => palawan
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [address] => bohol
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [address] => calabarson
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [address] => NCR
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [address] => baguio
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [address] => manila
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [address] => cagayan
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [address] => iligan
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [address] => sindangan
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [address] => dipolog
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [address] => calamba
            [mainDomain] => 
        )

)
```

i need to extract all address so i tried using

```
foreach ($mydata[0]['sddress'] as $key) {

    }
```

but iam recieving errors:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'address' in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/ruleswitcherandchecker/public/CTAchecker/index.php on line 131

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/ruleswitcherandchecker/public/CTAchecker/index.php on line 131
```

please help :(

Comment: hi thanks for the response, tried fixing the typo same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at that dump it seems you just need another set of `foreach` since its nested:

```
foreach($landerssss['domains'] as $mydata) {
    foreach ($mydata as $key) {
        echo $key['address']; // and so forth
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer it solved, i have another question. if i only want to extract the address from the second array. is this possible?

Comment: @ban just use `$landerssss['domains'][1]` to get the second batch

Comment: hi thanks for your help now the $mydata variable also has the second array ill try to figure out how to extract address with this since data structure changes .. will ask for help if i cant figure it out.. thanks a lot :D